# Не могу начать работу с react, локальный сервер не отображает изменений в app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Начал изучения reacta по роликам. Сравнил код с образцом не нашёл различий, но на локальном сервере не отображает изменения, подскажите в чем проблема.

```js
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        работа пошла
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

//ещё один метод который я пробовал так же не работает
//const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(root));
//root.render(<App/>)



App.js


const App = () => {
  return (
<div>text</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что код работает и ваш текст отображается, но при изменении кода не происходит автообновления страницы?

Comment: Нет, вообще пустая страница изначально. Через девтулс сам див рут показывает, но он пустой.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, добавил скрин с ошибками которые выдает девтулс, возможно, так будет понятнее.

Comment: А как вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: через терминал git bash команду npm start терминал ошибок не выдает.

Comment: Попробуйте перенести ваш код в https://codesandbox.io/ и посмотрите там всё запустится или нет. Если и там будут проблемы, то поделитесь вашей ссылкой и попробую разобраться. Если там всё запустится, то попробуйте удалить ваш проект и создать  с 0 новый. Так без доступа к вашей системе (как минимум мне) трудно сказать в чём проблема

Comment: А ещё попробуйте `import App from './App.js';` написать, быть может надо указать расширение вручную

Comment: Добавил расширение не помогло.

Comment: Не `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';`, а надо `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: Вы создавали проект через npx create-react-app <project_name>  ? Если нет, то попробуйте. Если он сразу же не запустится, то проблема не в коде.

Comment: Проджект нейм был задан. Проблема была решена вот этим Не import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';, а надо import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой рабочий пример, где выводится текст. Попробуйте начать с этого:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        DIV TEXT
      </div>
    );
}

// Рендеринг
ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

## UPD

Помогло изменение пути импорта. Не `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';`, а надо `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`;

Comment: Так же пустая страница, терминал ошибку не выдает. Девтулс дает единственную ошибку :Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at ./src/App.js (App.js:2:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (App.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1

Comment: @stargazerxx Покажите пожалуйста (дополнив вопрос) то как выглядит файловая система вашего проекта

Comment: Добавил вообще все в чем были какие то правки

Comment: @stargazerxx Уберите ссылки в `html`-е на скрипты `React` и оставьте `document.getElementById('root')` :) Я тут их вставил, потому что нельзя по другому запускать тут код `React`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-stonebraker-n7dnyy?file=/public/index.html Так же структуру из сандбокса попробовал запустить у себя в редакторе все равно пустая страница.

Comment: Спасибо большое, подошел ваш ответ с изменением import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';